# Date Ranges between 2 dates (Syntac)

Tags: php, mysql, date

This is driving me crazy!!! 
Here is the code that I am trying to put data for the last 31 days between 2 dates, NOW and 31 days later.

This code does not work:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$datetime = new DateTime($now);
$datetime->modify('+31 days');
$NEW_30 = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');

$get_time1ax = "select * from support_tickets WHERE start_date >= '".$now."' AND end_date <= '".$NEW_30."' ORDER BY problem_title ASC";
```

But this code does work? Do not understand this.

```
$get_time1ax = "select * from support_tickets WHERE start_date >= '2020-03-19' AND end_date <= '2020-04-19' ORDER BY problem_title ASC";
```

Notice the actual date is in the field and not a variable. Weird.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Does not pull the data between those dates. That is why it doe not work, if it did I would not be asking a question.

Comment: It may seem obvious to you, but it isn't obvious to everyone reading your question. You didn't state if your problem is generating the query with PHP or not getting expected results from the database. Considering that it's the latter, I'm unable to reproduce. Your code generates the query properly.

Comment: @El_Vanja I keep clicking on the Immutable docs >_<;

Comment: @Sammitch The reflex of a good developer

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to put data for the last 31 days between [...] now and 31 days later.

You can do date arithmetics directly in the database:

```
select * 
from support_tickets 
where start_date >= curent_date and end_date <= current_date + interval 31 day
```

Possibly, you mean 1 month when you say 31 days, so:

```
select * 
from support_tickets 
where start_date >= curent_date and end_date <= current_date + interval 1 month
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$current_date_plus_31 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+31 days',strtotime($current_date)));
```

this is how it works for me with today's date and in 31 days

Comment: This does not change the output in any way.

Comment: Seems like OP's problem is elsewhere. His code in the question generates the correct range.